# Obj-C: add Objects at indexes of Array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I am trying to add objects at certain indexes of an array to a new array. I have found a solution, but is there a more elegant way to do this? This is what I have.

```
 NSMutableArray *objectsToAdd = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in self.selectedIndexes)
    {
        for (Object *object in self.unsortedObjects) {
            if (indexPath.row == [self.unsortedObjects indexOfObject:object]) {
                [objectsToAdd addObject:object];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `self.selectedIndexes` is an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`. Hope help

```
NSMutableArray *objectsToAdd = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in self.selectedIndexes)
{
    if (indexPath.row < [self.unsortedObjects count]) {
        [objectsToAdd addObject:self.unsortedObjects[indexPath.row]] ;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is an NSMutableArray, you are correct. This is better. thank you.